# How can i read 'Encoded by' information of Mp3 File?

Tags: taglib-sharp

I can read album, artist, title and etc. with Taglib-sharp but i couldnt find out how to read 'encoded by' field like itunes does.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out.

```
tagFile = TagLib.File.Create(fileLocation);
TagLib.Id3v2.Tag tag5 = (TagLib.Id3v2.Tag)tagFile.GetTag(TagTypes.Id3v2);


                    IEnumerable<TagLib.Id3v2.Frame> frames = tag5.GetFrames();                   

                    foreach (TagLib.Id3v2.Frame frame in frames)
                    {
                        if (frame.FrameId.Data.SequenceEqual(new byte[] { 84, 69, 78, 67}))
                            fileAnlyRslt.EncodedWith = frame.ToString();
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution (uses LINQ):

```cs
var mp3File = TagLib.File.Create(path);
var tags = new TagLib.Id3v2.Tag(mp3File, 0);

var frame = tags.GetFrames()
                .Where(f => Encoding.UTF8.GetString(f.FrameId.Data) == "TENC")
                .First();
var encoder = frame != null ? frame.ToString() : "";
```